How to import fixtures in each Playwright test
I am writing some e2e tests using Playwright, and I have defined two fixtures:

one is for launching a browser with my chrome extension installed
other is for mocking an external api call so I can test an authenticated state

fixtures-auth.js
import { test } from './fixtures.js';
export { test, expect } from './fixtures.js';

test.beforeEach(async ({ context }) => {
    await context.route(
        'https://some.url.com/api/some-endpoint',
        async (route) => {
            if (route.request().serviceWorker()) {
                const json = {
                    //json content
                };
                await route.fulfill({ json });
            }
        },
    );
});

Currently I have two tests located in separate directories, but both of them having the same path to the fixture file. When I run them both, the fixture-auth is only applied to the first test and in the second one, despite the fixture being imported, it simply does not run the test.beforeEach.
import { test, expect } from '../fixtures-auth.js';

I want to run this beforeEach in every test to avoid code duplication, what am I doing wrong?
Additional info:
What I am trying to mock is an external API call happening in the background script of my chrome extension. When running the tests separately everything works because the fixtures-auth.js is imported, but when running both tests together it seems to be only importing once for the first test and in the second it just doesn't run test.beforeEach which I need for mocking.
fixtures.js content:
const base = require('@playwright/test');
const { chromium } = require('@playwright/test');
const path = require('path');

process.env.PW_EXPERIMENTAL_SERVICE_WORKER_NETWORK_EVENTS = '1';

exports.test = base.test.extend({
    context: async ({ }, use) => {
        const pathToExtension = path.join(__dirname, '../dist');
        const context = await chromium.launchPersistentContext('', {
            headless: false,
            args: [
                `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
                `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
            ],
        });
        await use(context);
        await context.close();
    },
    extensionId: async ({ context }, use) => {
        // for manifest v3:
        let [background] = context.serviceWorkers();
        if (!background)
            background = await context.waitForEvent('serviceworker');

        const extensionId = background.url().split('/')[2];
        await use(extensionId);
    },
});
exports.expect = base.expect;

My playwright config
const { defineConfig } = require('@playwright/test');

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';
module.exports = defineConfig({
    testDir: './playwright',
    fullyParallel: true,
    forbidOnly: false,
    retries: 0,
    maxFailures: 1,
    workers: 1,
    reporter: 'line',
    expect: {
        timeout: 10 * 1000,
    },
    use: {
        baseURL: baseURL,
        trace: 'on-first-retry',
        serviceWorkers: 'allow',
    },
    projects: [
        {
            name: 'chromium',
            use: { browserName: 'chromium' },
        },
    ],
    webServer: {
        command: 'npx http-server ./playwright',
        url: baseURL,
        reuseExistingServer: true,
    },
});


I added my Playwright config and fixtures.js content, not sure if anything else would be useful, please let me know if you have any recommendations.

In fixtures-auth.js shouldn't you import test from playwright...?

But in fixtures.js I extend base.test and add the extended test to exports, then it's imported inside fixtures-auth.js where the beforeEach is which I would like to run before every test case in files where fixtures-auth.js is imported.
Requiring test like this does not seem to help const test = require('@playwright/test');

It simply does not call beforeEach in the second test even though I import the fixtures-auth.js in both tests.
